# Is Fajans Rule valid for polyatomic anions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In my textbook its mentioned that BeCO3 (beryllium carbonate) is an ionic compound, but going according to fajans rules, small cation with high charge density and large anion should give a majorly covalent compound.

Comment: Relatively small, electronegative oxygen atoms in large anions are less polarizable than big single-atom anions like iodide.

Comment: Beryllium carbonate is unstable. Mismatch is size is too large, and carbonate have a general tendency to break down to CO2 and oxides.

Comment: For delocalized electrons, it does provide some insight. However, strictly speaking, Fajan rule is only applicable to atoms and ions. Hard-Soft Acid-Base theory is more widely applicable for polyatomic ions.